# What language should I use to build a small Costing App?

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, web-applications, business-intelligence

Am trying to build a Small Cost Calculation and Quotation App. Since Its not so big App, I was planning to use plain Javascript rather than using frameworks like Angular JS because i am not much familiar with it. Am I doing it right.

This will precisely have following :

### Front End (User Side)

1. User Input Interface where the User will Input the values in the required field. This will require to load different modules based on the kind of costing thats being calculated.
2. Quotation which will constantly update based on User Inputs and will have the options to Print, Save and Email the Quotation.

I would also need the ability to save the Quotation which can be edited anytime later on.

### Admin Panel

To Set Preferences (with Preferences I mean the rates / Unit and other details. I do not know if 'preferences' is the proper term to use)

### Backend

The Backend will comprise of Cost Calculation Based on the User Inputs and the Preferences Set. How do I do that.

For eg I select a component that requires 10kg of "A" Product where as the Rate / Kg should already be set using Admin Panel

Apart from that, The Costing Calculation workout should also be displayed on request if the admin is logged in.

### Database

I prefer mysql as thats wot I am familiar with.

Would I really find help if I host the project on github. Why would someone help me code.

Is there anything like coding online without installing framework like WAMP.

Can anyone advise me if what I am doing is right or not .

Answer (score 1):

Let's start by seeing the big picture. The basic architecture is like this:

```
Client      -> Server   -> Database 
Frontend    -> Backend  -> Repository 
Javascript  -> ?        -> MySql
```

And let's see what you know and are comfortable with - Javascript and MySql. To avoid learning a new language/framework, you should be quite OK with the above technologies.

You just have a missing piece ie. scritping at the server or backend. Php is a good free choice. However if you know other server side languages like Java, those will be fine too. If you can list the languages you know then more specific help can come. Have a look at [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) since you are already familiar with javascript.

You don't need to host in github. There are many hosting servers available which makes it very easy to run php/mysql if you proceed with that.

Answer (score 0):

You have asked lots of questions. i will try to answer them briefly

1) Yes you can use Angular JS for the costing app. You can also use plain Javascript / JQuery too.

2) I dont understand this preferences thing properly but if your first question and this is taken into account then i guess using php as a scripting language will solve many of these things (for example 'saving the quotations for future use etc)

3) The admin panel thing and display of the particular app after login can be totally done with any scripting languages for example PHP or anything else of your choice.

4) A database like mysql can be used, its good, pretty standard. I dont think you can 'host' a database driven website on Github. You can make a repo of the files there though.

5) Lastly you can code online without using WAMP, XAMPP etc. There are lots of cloud ide-s. For example Cloud9, Nitrous, Codeanywhere. Check those out.

If you find my answer as helpful check the tick beside my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks  but would I really need to use PHP as I am not much familiar with it . Cant Javascript be used to take the data to database ( if thats what Backend means as I am still quiet confused with this backend term)

Comment: No, Javascript cannot be used to 'take' the data to the database because it is a client side language. You need to use a server side scripting language to do the part of inserting data to the database like PHP, ASP etc. However you can use JS based MEAN stack to buld the app, that is entirely JS based

Answer (score 0):

Instead of considering the size you should consider its importance and should decide its impact in market..

Instead of using simple JavaScript you should probably go for AngularJs since its a framework..and frameworks since they have their own methods of implementation and their own designs they are likely to be used as they keep your code clean and handle most of the things themselves so you do not really waste your time writing unnecessary code..

I would recommend you to go for

- Angular-for frontend
- Spring-for backend
- MySql-for database

Try to use frameworks as they will surely help you building low cost app